# The unnamed module reads package org.apache.log4j from both slf4j.log4j12 and log4j

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I've followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKIMGH0l3Wo) to use javafx in a gradle java project. All was ok until I tried to add JOpenGeocoding dependency:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile("com.byteowls:jopencage:1.3.0")
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.29'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
    version = '11.0.2'
}
```

and

**Main.java**

```
package sample;

import com.byteowls.jopencage.JOpenCageGeocoder;
import com.byteowls.jopencage.model.JOpenCageResponse;
import com.byteowls.jopencage.model.JOpenCageReverseRequest;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        JOpenCageGeocoder jOpenCageGeocoder = new JOpenCageGeocoder("dba40429c8ae43b78ae293bc0d221fb5");

        JOpenCageReverseRequest request = new JOpenCageReverseRequest(41.40015, 2.15765);
        request.setLanguage("es"); // prioritize results in a specific language using an IETF format language code (espanol)
        request.setNoDedupe(true); // don't return duplicate results
        request.setLimit(5); // only return the first 5 results (default is 10)
        request.setNoAnnotations(true); // exclude additional info such as calling code, timezone, and currency
        request.setMinConfidence(3); // restrict to results with a confidence rating of at least 3 (out of 10)

        JOpenCageResponse response = jOpenCageGeocoder.reverse(request);

        // get the formatted address of the first result:
        String formattedAddress = response.getResults().get(0).getFormatted();

        System.out.println(formattedAddress);
    }
}
```

and this is the

**module-info.java** file

```
module TroppAdvisorDesktop.main {
     requires javafx.controls;
     requires javafx.fxml;
     requires jopencage;

     opens sample;
}
```

Unfortunately when I build this project, several errors pop up as you can see here: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhJhQ.png)

- How can I fix?

I noticed that if i remove `compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.29'` from `build.bradle` file, it executes correctly but there are some errors that appear anyway such as:

> warning: unknown enum constant Include.NON_NULL
> reason: class file for com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Include not found
> 1 warning

> Task :Main.main()

Travessera de Gràcia, 142, 08001 Barcelona, España

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java Platform Module System Requirements](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/reqs/), packages of the same name, but from different modules are not allowed to interfere with each other.

See:

> Non-interference — The Java compiler, virtual machine, and run-time system must ensure that modules that contain packages of the same name do not interfere with each other. If two distinct modules contain packages of the same name then, from the perspective of each module, all of the types and members in that package are defined only by that module. Code in that package in one module must not be able to access package-private types or members in that package in the other module.

Because some of your transitive dependencies are not modular, they end up on the unnamed module (the classpath), where their package names interfere. The fact that this is not an issue in a non-modular Java 9+ project is actually a [java compiler bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215739).

In Gradle, you can try [excluding one of the dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps) that causes the conflict as a workaround. But bear in mind that this may cause unwanted behaviour at runtime.

A better long term solution would be to contact the developers of the libraries that are causing the conflict and urge them to fix it.

You can use the Gradle `dependencyInsight` to determine the problematic dependencies, e.g.

```
gradle dependencyInsight --configuration runtimeClasspath --dependency log4j
```